# Structuremap: problem registering all types plus a default instance that aggregates all other instances

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have an interface:

```
public interface IFoo {
    void Foo ():
}
```

And an implementation of IFoo that is intended to aggregate all other instance of IFoo that are registered by StructureMap scanning:

```
public class CompositeFoo : IFoo
{
      public void Foo ()
      {
           foreach (IFoo f in _foos)
                f.Foo ();
      }

      public CompositeFoo (IEnumerable<IFoo> foos)
      {
           _foos = foos;
      }

      IEnumerable<IFoo> _foos;
}
```

In my StructureMap initialization, I'm doing:

```
Container c = new Container (x =>
{
    x.For<IFoo> ().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<CompositeFoo> ();
    x.Scan (s => {
        s.WithDefaultConventions ();
        s.ExcludeType<CompositeFoo> ();
        s.AddAllTypes<IFoo> ();
    });
});
```

However, when trying to resolve an instance of IFoo, I get an exception about a bidirectional (circular) dependancy.

I've attempted to do a conditional registration of CompositeFoo:

```
x.For<IGlobalConfiguration> ().ConditionallyUse (c =>
{
    c.If (ctx => ctx.ParentType != typeof (CompositeGlobalConfiguration)})
        .ThenIt.Is.Type<CompositeGlobalConfiguration> ();
});
```

but to no avail... Suggestions?